# using ${resource} in a separated thread?

Tags: multithreading, grails, resources, groovy

I want to perform a simple task ! but dont know if it is possible or not!

I have a groovy class which implements Runnable and it has been running using an ThreadPool! what I want to do in my Runnable class is the following:

```
    public void run() {
          EventPhoto.withTransaction { status ->

                EventPhoto photo = new EventPhoto(event:eventInstance)

                photo.imageUrl = "${resource(dir:'images/uploads',file:image.name, absolute:true)}"
                photo.thumbnailUrl = "${resource(dir:'images/uploads',file:thumb.name, absolute:true)}"
          }
    }
```

The thing is, as my thread is not running inside the webrequest I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are
>   you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request,
>   or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If
>   you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
>   message, your code is probably running outside of
>   DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.

So Is there anyway to still use $resource() ??

thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's not the call to `save()` that's generating this erroe?

Comment: @Don yep! i tried the same code w/o ${resource()} and it works!

Comment: I removed the call to `save()` from your post to avoid this confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is some information](http://ldaley.com/post/5378542618/using-grails-tags-where-you-cant-use-grails-tags) that will show you how to accomplish what you are trying to do. Also note that it advises that what you are doing is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Your background thread does not, by default, have access to the Hibernate session used to persist your Photo.  You can use a plugin like [Executor](https://github.com/basejump/grails-executor) to save domain objects in a background thread.

Comment: My problem is not persisting! the persistence is working fine! the problem is using "${resource()}"